# DataGridTableStyle VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, datagrid

I am using the following code to try and apply a style to my datagrid but nothing is happening, no columns are created at all, I just get a blank DataGrid:

Can someone please advise what I am doing wrong?

```
    adapter.Fill(ds, "dttest")

    DataGrid1.DataSource = ds.Tables("dttest")

    Dim ts As New DataGridTableStyle()
    ts.MappingName = "dttest"

    Dim column1 As New DataGridTextBoxColumn()
    column1.MappingName = "serv"
    column1.Width = 25
    column1.HeaderText = "Serv"
    ts.GridColumnStyles.Add(column1)

    Dim column2 As New DataGridTextBoxColumn()
    column2.MappingName = "op"
    column2.Width = 50
    ts.GridColumnStyles.Add(column2)

    Dim column3 As New DataGridTextBoxColumn()
    column3.MappingName = "deptime"
    column3.Width = 50
    ts.GridColumnStyles.Add(column3)


    Me.DataGrid1.TableStyles.Add(ts)
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like you have called DataGrid1.DataBind().

Comment: There is no member DataBind for DataGrid1